# What is the expected value of a standard normal random variable given value is positive?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

Am not sure if I'm wording this correctly.
But say we take huge sample of standard normal random variables.  Then we separate out positive values.  What would be average of the positive values ?  What would it approach as sample size got larger and larger.

Comment: I just did some calculation and it should be sqrt(2)/sqrt(pi).   BUT intuitively I thought answer would be 75th percentile b/c here 50% of positive values are below and 50% above the 75th percentile.  But this is wrong.  75th percentile is z=0.674 and sqrt(2)/sqrt(pi) is about 0.798

Comment: The long right tail would tend to pull the mean to the right.

Comment: @stevek : Your reasoning correctly identifies the median but not the mean.  For symmetric distributions that have a mean, those are the same.  But this is not symmetric.

Comment: Thanks, I keep thinking mean is part that balances the areas but this appears to be median.

Answer (score 1):

The density is
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} \frac2{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-x^2/2} & \text{if }x>0, \\[6pt] 0 & \text{if }x<0. \end{cases}
$$
So the expected value is
$$
\int_0^\infty xf(x)\,dx = \frac2{\sqrt{2\pi}}  \int_0^\infty e^{-x^2/2} \big(x\,dx\big) = \frac2{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_0^\infty e^{-u}\,du = \frac2{\sqrt{2\pi}} \cdot 1 = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{align}
P(x=x_0 \mid x>0) &= \frac{P(x=x_0)}{P(x>0)} \\
&= \frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-x_0^2/2}}{\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-z^2/2} dz} \\
&= \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} e^{-x_0^2/2}
\end{align} 
$$

So

$$
E(x \mid x>0) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \int_0^\infty e^{-z^2/2} z\, dz
= \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}
$$

Comment: You're missing some minus signs in exponents.

Comment: @Michael - thanks

Comment: I guess the density can be evaluated at $x=x_0$, not the probability.

Comment: @Seyhmus that's right too, I'm surprised I wasn't downvoted by now, heh